# Using relative Path in NodeJS and express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently trying to figure out nodejs and express.

At the Moment I have a small sample project running on my local machine.

When accessing /login I want to be redirected to the login.html file.

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/login/login.html'));
})
```

does the job quiet nicely.

I had the css directly in the header and now I'd like to access a shared folder from the html site itself.

**File Structure:**

```
- project
    +--- node_modules
    +--- package.json
    +--- index.js
    +--- shared/
       +--- css/
          +--- style.css
       +--- images/
    +--- login/
       +--- login.js
       +--- login.html
```

I found the following solution in the express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html and it's - at least what I think - what I need.

currently I'm only using index.js and login.js

how do I actually use the provided static files? Am I supposed to provide them in the index.js?

**index.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname + './static')));

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world!');
})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/login/login.html'));
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on http://localhost:' + port);
})
```

**login.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shared/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-form">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <form action="auth" method="POST">
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your static path to and allow express to serve static file

```
//here login is the folder name which contain index.html file so you need to define that path
var public = path.join(__dirname, 'login');

app.use(express.static(public));

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(public, 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: thank you very much! I adapted it and put it directly into the index.js of the app to provide the public file everywhere (for testing)